# How to base a game value in C# on its magnitude from 0 instead of its real value?

Tags: c#

```
if (col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude>GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude) {

      Debug.Log("collision");
```

As the velocity can be positive or negative, how to make it so the direction of the object is disregarded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for absolute value of a number

```
Math.Abs(someNumber)
```

For example

```
Math.Abs(-1) // == 1
Math.Abs(1) // == 1
```